# Minecraft DNS SRV record not working

Tags: networking, dns, minecraft

I've added an `A` record to my domain with the name of `mcserverbox`, TTL of `1m` and a value of `myiphere`. I've also added a `SRV` record to my domain with the name of `_minecraft.tcp.mc.mydomain.com`, and the value of `0 5 25565 mcserverbox.mydomain.com.` Yet when I try to connect to `mc.mydomain.com` in Minecraft, I get the error `io.netty.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information`. For contrast, trying `fakesubdomain.mydomain.com` gives the error `Unknown host`. **`mcserverbox` is on my subnet.**

```
$ dig _minecraft._tcp.mc.mydomain.com SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.17-Ubuntu <<>> _minecraft._tcp.mc.mydomain.com SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12741
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_minecraft._tcp.mc.mydomain.com. IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_minecraft._tcp.mc.mydomain.com. 60 IN SRV 0 5 25565 mcserverbox.mydomain.com.
```

I've waited about an hour for it to work, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT port forwarding works, because other people (not on my subnet) can access my server by it's IP

Comment: Peanut gallery (this doesn't address your SRV question directly), but if you are using `mcserverbox.mydomain.com`, perhaps you should just give that out. If you are using port 25565, unless I am mistaken, things should connect automatically (no port needs to be specified).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the problem was that `mcserverbox` was on my same subnet. It worked for other people, and i set up a subdomain for connectings on my subnet.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT could you post your comments in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple items regarding your issue:

1. If your internal domain name is the same as your external domain and your internal domain is not defined as a subdomain, then *you likely need to setup an internal DNS record pointing to the internal (or maybe external) IP address of your MC server*.

   - I always setup domains with a subdomain internally so this is not an issue for example `in.mydomain.com`
2. Consider using [`ping`](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) and [`tracert`](https://ss64.com/nt/tracert.html) with the DNS name and the IP address to troubleshoot and compare the results of the method that works and doesn't work.